# SQL Server CE auto-increment issue

Tags: sql-server-ce

I would like to remove auto-increment of a column from SQL Server CE. I couldn't remove auto-increment come whatever I do. Is it possible by altering the table? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what have you tried already ? did it gave errors  or whatever ?

Comment: create a new column, copy values, drop the ident column, rename the new column

Comment: is it sql-server or sql-ce?

Comment: I am using SQL-CE

Answer (score 1):

```
        The easiest way would be:

      1)  Open SQL Server Management Studio.
      2)  Locate Server > DataBase > Table.
      3)  Right Click on the Table > Select Design.
      4) In the design window, Highlight the column you want to modify.
      5) In the Column Properties Window browse to Identity Specification > Is  Identity And set to No.

 --   OR BY ALtering The Table You Can remove the auto-increment column

      CREATE TABLE test(col1 INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL, col2 VARCHAR(10) NULL);

        ALTER TABLE test ADD col3 INT NULL;

        UPDATE test SET col3 = col1;

        ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN col1;

        EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.test.col3', 'col1', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: will the drop column work if col1 is marked as primary key ?

Comment: @GuidoG Yes It will be